# How to target a specific Admin Config section with a layout update

Tags: adminhtml, layout

It is relatively easy to target the `adminhtml_system_config_edit` node with layout updates in a layout.xml file by using:

```
<adminhtml_system_config_edit>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><file>jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js</file></action>
        <action method="addJs"><file>jquery/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js</file></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_system_config_edit>
```

However, I would like to target a specific configuration section instead. Something along the lines of (I know this is totally incorrect and doesn't follow the `module/controller/action` naming, simply to clarify the intent):

```
<adminhtml_system_config_edit_my_section>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><file>jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js</file></action>
        <action method="addJs"><file>jquery/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js</file></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_system_config_edit_my_section>
```

But alas, this does not work. How can I target my specific section with layout XML?

Comment: Where do you want to add the JS? I don't understand you. What do you mean by "specific configuration section"?

Comment: I know I specifically mention `addJs`, but it is irrelevant that my example is using this specific action.

Comment: When you define a new admin system configuration section with a module, the section name is passed as an argument in the url structure, `admin/system_config/edit/section/my_section`.

Answer (score 5):

As benmarks mentioned a two-step approach would be needed, ie not possible with layout xml alone.

You could use

```
<adminhtml_system_config_edit>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="namespace/adminhtml_custom" name="namespace_adminhtml_custom" as="namespace_adminhtml_custom" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_system_config_edit>
```

And then in your block class extended from Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('section') == 'YOUR_SECTION') {
        $this->getParentBlock()->addJs('path/to/javascript.js');
    }
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this. Because of all of the model and block instantiation possibilities (see [`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form` [link]](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php)), there are several two-step solutions. One would be to add your `<script>` tag in via a field `<comment>` using a `CDATA` tag.

Comment: The question mentions the `addJs` action in `head`, but really I was thinking more broadly such as calling various blocks' references and being able to essentially instantiate my own simple blocks on various configuration screens. I was thinking it would actually make sense to be able to target something such as calling a node of `adminhtml_system_config_edit` and then a reference of `my_section` and then be able to do some layout magic, but I guess this is pretty much where the backend and frontend aren't really playing the same game.

Comment: "instantiate my own simple blocks"? See `Mage_GoogleCheckout`'s [*system.xml*](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/GoogleCheckout/etc/system.xml#L189) - anything in `<frontend_modle>` is a block class.